# Spread values to an object (Computed property names)

Tags: javascript

I would like to get a review of something,

I have a function that creates an array of objects for a Drop-Down component (react-select).

The function gets `data`, `valueKey`, `labelKey` and `otherInfo` from an object,
and creates the array of objects based on the `valueKey` and the `labelKey`.

```
const createOptions = ({data, valueKey, labelKey, ...otherInfo}) => {
  return data.map(item => 
    ({ 
      value: item[valueKey],
      label: item[labelKey],
      ...appendOtherInfo(item, otherInfo)
    })
  );
}
```

most of the time, `valueKey` and `labelKey` are enough, but there are some cases where there is additional info to add to each object, which is `otherInfo`, which is an object as well.

`appendOtherInfo()` function creates an object which is then appended to each object that `map` iteration returned.

```
const appendOtherInfo = (item, otherInfo) => {
  return Object.entries(otherInfo).reduce((total, [key, value]) => {
    total[key] = item[value];

    return total;
  }, {});
}
```

for example, after calling `createOptions()` with the array:

```
const people = [
  {id: '123', name: 'Dani', type: 'a', city: 'Rome'},
  {id: '222', name: 'John', type: 'a', city: 'London'},
  {id: '333', name: 'David', type: 'b', city: 'Madrid'}
]
```

and the rest of the info to create the new array,

```
createOptions({
  data: people,
  valueKey: 'id',
  labelKey: 'name',
  type: 'type',
  capitalCity: 'city'
});
```

The result is:

```
[
  {
    "value": "123",
    "label": "Dani",
    "type": "a",
    "capitalCity": "Rome"
  },
  {
    "value": "222",
    "label": "John",
    "type": "a",
    "capitalCity": "London"
  },
  {
    "value": "333",
    "label": "David",
    "type": "b",
    "capitalCity": "Madrid"
  }
]
```

In the `appendOtherInfo()` function, I used `Object.entries` and `reduce` to create the additional info for each object.
It's working as expected, but I'd like to know if there is a better/easier way to achieve the same result.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is okay; although I'd make `appendOtherInfo()` a local function of `createOptions()`. **But** the problem is, in terms of *abstraction* - you build a function that you want to re-use and that gives you the *feeling* it is generic enough for all future use cases for your drop down. However, there are two problems - your *"generic"* function is just generic *enough* for *flat* objects and cannot easily handle nested objects.

Furthermore because it's only argument is an object, different properties in it have different meanings - this is not good for code readability.

So my advice is, why bother writing something that is seemingly generic, but actually not generic enough that it will ever see proper reuse.

Instead simply use direct mappers; they are more readable and they give you the full flexibility, so instead of:

```
<react-select options = { createOptions({
  data: people,
  valueKey: 'id',
  labelKey: 'name',
  type: 'type',
  capitalCity: 'city'
})}>/
```

Simply do:

```
<react-select options = { people.map(peopl => {
  value: peopl.id,
  label: peopl.name,
  type: peopl.type
  capitalCity: peopl.city
}
}>/
```

*(I did not look up `<react-select>`'s API)*:
Do not hide simple *extracting and remapping* behind functions if there is no need to - make code explicit and readable.

You can happily use *destructuring* with *renaming* and *...*, if you only need to map label and value as well:

```
<react-select options = { people.map(peopl => ({
  const {id: value, name: label, ...other} = peopl;
  return {value, name, ...other}})
)}>/
```

Or to be explicit and combining above:

```
<react-select options = { people.map(peopl => ({
  const {id: value, name: label, type, city: capitalCity} = peopl;
  return {value, name, type, capitalCity}})
)}>/
```